# Cygwin create .tar.gz not working within for loop

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin, tar

I have a series of folders, each of which contains assorted subfolders, files etc. I am trying to zip these up into a .tar.gz

Target folder structure is e.g. G:/datastore and below that the folders to zip are simply named yyyymmdd

Destination would be e.g. G:/datastore/archive and file would unsurprisingly be named yyyymmdd.tar.gz

The longform command to do this one daily folder at a time works just fine....

tar -czvf /cygdrive/g/datastore/archive/20160108.tar.gz /cygdrive/g/datastore/20160108

But trying to use a for loop to have this chug away zipping multiple days fails...

Syntax I tried thus;

for day in 20160107 20160108 ;do tar -czvf /cygdrive/g/datastore/archive/{day}.tar.gz /cygdrive/g/datastore/{day} ;done

Error I get is

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /cygdrive/e/tickstore/datastore/{day}: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

If I try navigating so I am sitting in the target directory and removing the file path I get a slightly different but fundamentally equivalent error;

Syntax thus;

cd /cygdrive/g/datastore

for day in 20160107 20160108 ;do tar -czvf /cygdrive/g/datastore/archive/{day}.tar.gz {day} ;done

tar: {day}: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: I would suggest that {day} would need to be ${day} or $(day)

Comment: Damn. Rookie error. Thanks Raman that fixes it. Feeling embarrassed now.....

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on what @Raman Sailopal said in the comments

You can use the `echo` command to test your variables are being correctly used, see these examples, note the use of the dollar sign before your variable `day`:

using `{day}`

```
$ for day in 20160107 20160108 ;do echo {day} ;done
```

output:

```
{day}
{day}
```

---

using `${day}`:

```
$ for day in 20160107 20160108 ;do echo ${day} ;done
```

output:

```
20160107
20160108
```